Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: No package name is given
I cannot understand how to marshal data to XML. I always get this error:

Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: No package name is given

Imports:
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext
import org.apache.camel.converter.jaxb.JaxbDataFormat

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement

Class:
@XmlRootElement(name = "message")
class Message {
    @XmlElement(name = "content")
    String content

    Message() {}

    Message(String content) {
        this.content = content
    }
}

My code:
CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext()

// Настройка JaxbDataFormat
JaxbDataFormat jaxbDataFormat = new JaxbDataFormat(Message.class.getPackage().getName())

context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
    @Override
    void configure() {
        // Маршрут для маршалинга строки в XML
        from("direct:start")
            .process { exchange ->
                Message message = new Message("Hello, World!")
                exchange.getIn().setBody(message)
            }
            .marshal(jaxbDataFormat)
            .to("file:output?fileName=message.xml&charset=utf-8")
            .log("Message object marshaled to XML and written to file")
    }
})

How to marshal data to XML?

Jaxb recognizes the location of your class and will marshal it correctly. So you need to create the package and move your class under that folder after all correct your class package and then i hope everything will work correctly.

@newuserua_ext I created package and moved class under that folder. But now I have new error: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions. That is all error, without any axplanation of this error. Do you have suggestions?

you should trace out printStackTrace, not the pure exception. Blind comment for the exception; you should bind object before (un)marshall
